# Caffe compilation fails: make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/data_transformer.o] Error 1

Tags: linux, makefile, fedora, caffe, gflags

I am trying to build caffe after the instructions on http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html#prerequisites
When compiling i get the following error:
(I use Fedora 22)

```
$make all
CXX src/caffe/data_transformer.cpp
In file included from ./include/caffe/blob.hpp:8:0,
                 from ./include/caffe/data_transformer.hpp:6,
                 from src/caffe/data_transformer.cpp:6:
./include/caffe/common.hpp:5:27: fatal error: gflags/gflags.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:516: recipe for target '.build_release/src/caffe/data_transformer.o' failed
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/data_transformer.o] Error 1
```

What am i doin wrong?

Comment: You appear to have missed the `gflags` dependency (or at least the `gflags` header files).

Comment: after installing gflags via "sudo dnf install gflags" i still get the same error?
any ideas?

Comment: Try installing `gflags-devel` or `gflags-dev` or whatever the development header package is.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install missing dependencies (gflags).

Fedora/RHEL/CentOS: `sudo yum install gflags-devel`

Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install libgflags-dev`

There are also instructions for other dependencies:

Fedora/RHEL/CentOS :http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_yum.html

Ubuntu: http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html

Answer (score 0):

To install missing gflag dependencies

```
wget https://github.com/schuhschuh/gflags/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
cd gflags-master
mkdir build && cd build
export CXXFLAGS="-fPIC" && cmake .. && make VERBOSE=1
make 
sudo make install
```

Comment: This fails for me: -- Could NOT find GFlags (missing:  GFLAGS_INCLUDE_DIR GFLAGS_LIBRARY) 
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "1.8.3.1") 
-- Could NOT find Glog (missing:  GLOG_INCLUDE_DIR GLOG_LIBRARY) 
-- Found PROTOBUF: /usr/lib64/libprotobuf.so  
-- Found PROTOBUF Compiler: /usr/bin/protoc
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find HDF5 (missing: HDF5_LIBRARIES HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS)